# How to return only lines that do not match any values of an array?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm attempting to compare each line in a CSV file to each and every element (strings) I have stored in an array using Perl. I want to return/print-to-file the line from the CSV file only if it is not matched by any of the strings in the array. I've tried numerous kinds of loops to achieve this, but have not only not found a solution, but none of my attempts is really giving me clues as to where I'm going wrong. Below are a few samples of the loops I've tried:

```
while (<CSVFILE>) {
   foreach $i (@lines) {
        print OUTPUTFILE $_ if $_ !~ m/$i/;
     }; #foreach
}; #while
```

AND:

```
foreach $i (@lines) {
open (CSVFILE , "< $csv") or die "Can't open $csv for read: $!";
  while (<CSVFILE>) {
    if ($_ !~ m/$i/) {
      print OUTPUTFILE $_;
    }; #if
  }; #while
close (CSVFILE) or die "Cannot close $csv: $!";
}; #foreach
```

Here is a sample of the CSV file I am attempting:

```
1,c.03_05delAAG,null,71...
2,c.12T>G,null,24T->G,5...
3,c.87C>T,null,96C->T,82....
```

And the array elements (with regex escape characters):

```
c\.12T\>G
c\.97A\>C
```

Assuming only the above as input data, I would hope to get back:

```
1,c.03_05delAAG,null,71...
3,c.87C>T,null,16C->T....
```

since they do not contain any of the elements from the array. Is this a situation where Hashes come into play? I don't have a great handle on them yet, aside from the standard "dictionary" definition. If anyone could help me get my head around this problem it would be greatly appreciated. A this point I might just do it manually as there isn't *that many* and I need this out of the way ASAP, but since I wasn't able to find any answers searching anywhere else I figured it was worthwhile asking.

Comment: I have strict and warning set, but I when I run the script works fine but either gives a blank CSV as output or just re-prints the original. Am I missing something incredibly obvious here?

Answer (score 2):

Use Perl 5.10.1 or better, so you can apply [smart matching](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Smart-matching-in-detail).
Also, don't use the implicit `$_` when you're dealing with two loops, it gets too confusing and is error prone.

The following code (untested) might do the trick:

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

...

my @regexes = map { qr{$_} } @lines;

open my $out, '>', $outputfile;
open my $csv, '<', $csvfile;

while (my $line = <$csv>) {
    print $out $line unless $line ~~ @regexes;
}

close $csv;
close $out;
```

The reason your code doesn't work, by the way, is that it will print a line if *any* of the elements in `@lines` don't match, and that will always be the case.

Comment: "The reason your code doesn't work..." Wow, ok! I think that was the incredibly obvious thing I was missing. Well, I clearly have some reading/updating to do. I will post here whether it worked/what worked once I get everything sorted out. Thank you for the brisk response. As frustrating as Perl can be at times, the community is tremendous. Thanks